# DJANGO is_ajax two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

In one page, I have two forms. The first is submitted by ajax and the second is classic (submit by django).

I have a function ajax which get values of the first form and send it to view :

```
 $.post("http://localhost:8000/pageMa",{"donnees":donnees}).done(function(data){window.location.reload();});
```

For recognize what is the form submitted, I check if the form is ajax or no :

```
if request.is_ajax():
    ...
```

But request.is_ajax() is False...

I try this :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8000/pageMa",
    data : {"donnees":donnees}, 
    success: function(data) {
         alert("Success");
    },
    crossDomain: false
});
```

But I'm affrait that crossDomain:false isn't good for the security of website

Comment: Can you go to the network tab of your browser's devtools and check the request that is sent to the server? Specifically, look for a `X-requested-with` header.

Comment: `jQuery.ajax()` defaults to http.GET if you don't tell it to use POST. Try `method: "POST",` in the ajax method call.